# My IF loop does not stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a animated text output in html page. But in my javascript code, IF statement does not stop even the logic is out of the condition.

```
var wss_i = 0;
var wss_array = ["Programmer", "Developer", "Brother"];
var wss_elem;

function wssNext() {
    wss_i++;
    wss_elem.style.opacity = 0;
    if (wss_i > (wss_array.length - 1)) {
        wss_1 = 0;
    }
    console.log(wss_i);
    setTimeout('wssSlide()', 1000);
}

function wssSlide() {
    wss_elem.innerHTML = wss_array[wss_i];
    wss_elem.style.opacity = 1;
    setTimeout('wssNext()', 2000);
}
```

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout

Answer (score 9):

Correct variable should be used.

*Use*

```
wss_i = 0;
```

*instead of*

```
wss_1 = 0;
```

Comment: Oh wow...even in console debugging i dint notice. Thanks mate.